# Add Search suggestion to the header of recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I have an Recyclerview adapter class and searchbox as a header of recyclerview.
Everything is working fine.Now i want to get search suggestion while i type  first few letters of items of Recyclerview. Using AutoCompletetextView we needs to pass adapter of Recyclerview:
setAdapter(adapter) but my problem is how should i pass adapter as i am in adapter class.

Comment: It would be helpful to show us your code and where in code your problem is. But what I understood from your question, try to use ["this" keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) as setAdapter(this). Let me know how it work.

Comment: it doesnot take this too. I have defined searchbox inside viewholder

Answer (score 0):

use after arraylist or dataset values changed

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```